# Style Top Nav Bar IOS

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native

[image]

Hello,

I am trying to change the top nav bar color to light blue as well. I've looked into the StatusBar component, but no luck. Is it possible to customize the top nav bar?

Running this on ios simulator, Code below:

```
class SplashScreen extends Component { 
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.viewStyle}>
                <StatusBar
                    backgroundColor='#E3EFFF'
                />
                <Text></Text>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

const styles = {
    viewStyle: {
        backgroundColor: '#E3EFFF',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        flex: 1
    }
};

export default SplashScreen;
```

Comment: yes it is possible to customize it.

Comment: That's awesome! Could you please show me how?

Comment: try to Set the tint color of the nav bar.

Comment: No luck, I don't know if StatusBar corresponds to the whole white region in the picture.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to look up these react-native navigation libraries https://reactnavigation.org/ and https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/#/.

They provide the way to customize the navbar color and other properties for your use case. Other than that, I think there is no pure react-native solution for this.